# Do C compilers discard unused functions when statically linking to .a file?

Tags: compiling, c, libraries, compiler, static-linking

Say I have a C program `main.c` that statically links to `libmine.a`. Statically linking to a library causes library functions to be embedded into the main executable at compile time.

If `libmine.a` were to feature functions that weren't used by `main.c`, would the compiler (e.g. GCC) discard these functions?

This question is inspired by the "common messaging" that using static libraries make executables larger, so I'm curious if the compiler at least strips away unused code from an archive file.

Comment: It sounds like a question that squarely belongs on Stack Overflow. And probably already has been asked and answered there.

Comment: Some leads: *[Do unused functions get optimized out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215782/)* and *[Do compilers remove unused functions, definitions, variables, macros, includes, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782515/)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen funny how the answers here far outperform the linked answers on a site I agree the question belongs to.

Comment: At https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/how-to-remove-unused-c-c-symbols-with-gcc-and-ld/76695645#76695645 I dumped some runnable examples with `objdump` analysis. Results should be the same if you pass the `.o` object files separately or the `.a` by itself at link time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

By default, linkers handle object files as a whole. In your example, the executable will end up containing the code from `main.c` (`main.o`), and any object files from `libmine.a` (which is an archive of object files) required to provide all the functions used by `main.c` (transitively).

So the linker won’t necessarily include *all* of `libmine.a`, but the granularity it can use isn’t functions (by default), it’s object files (strictly speaking, sections). The reason for this is that when a given `.c` file is compiled to an object file, information from the source code is lost; in particular, the end of a function isn’t stored, only its start, and since multiple functions can be combined, it’s very difficult to determine from an object file what can actually be removed if a function is unused.

It is however possible for compilers and linkers to do better than this if they have access to the extra information needed. For example, the LightspeedC programming environment on ’80s Macs could use projects as libraries, and since it had the full source code in such cases, it would only include functions that were actually needed.

On more modern systems, the compiler can be told to produce object files which allow the linker to handle functions separately. With GCC, build your `.o` files with the `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` options enabled, and link the final program with the `--gc-sections` option. This does have an impact, notably by preventing certain categories of optimisation; see [discard unused functions in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36033595/4500798) for details.

Another option you can use with modern compilers and linkers is link-time optimisation; enable this with `-flto`. When optimisation is enabled (*e.g.* `-O2` when compiling the object files), the linker will not include unused functions in the resulting binary. This works even without `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`.

Comment: This answer says "modern compilers", but I'm pretty sure LightSpeed C on my Mac back in 1989 or so would only link in functions that were explicitly used.

Comment: How does this interact with link-time optimization (`-flto`), which defers certain code generation to link time? If that option is passed, does that allow the linker to perform the optimizations that it would ordinarily be prevented from performing by `--function-sections -fdata-sections --gc-sections`?

Comment: @larsks that depended on how you defined the libraries in Lightspeed — “projects as libraries” would only pull in functions that were actually used, “binary libraries” (`.lib` files) were coarse-grained.

Comment: @CodyGray with LTO (and optimisation, so `-O2 -flto` in practice) the linker will eliminate unused functions from the resulting binary, even if the object files were built *without* `-ffunction-sections`.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. But it is on a module level, not on a function.

For example, you have two source files: foo_goo.c and bar.c

```
// foo_goo.c
int foo() { .. };
int goo() { .. };
```

```
// bar.c
int bar() { .. };
```

Compile them into `foo_goo.o` and `bar.o`, and put both `.o` into the archive `libmine.a`.

Now, in your `main()` you are calling only the `foo()` function.

```
// main.c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   return foo();
}
```

Compile this source file into `main.o` and link with the `.a`.

The linker will see the function `foo()` in a module `foo_goo.o` and will use it, the `main()` will reference the `foo()` function, and the `goo()` function would be added into final binary, but not refrenced. The `bar.o` would be ignored, since none of the names in it were referenced.

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with the compiler. It is the linker which puts all the objects needed into a single file if you use static linking.

That will be the main() function of your C program, everything possibly used by main, everything used by something possibly used by something used by something used by main and so on. If there is a function that cannot possibly be called or an object that cannot possibly be accessed then the linker can leave it out. If an object file contains five functions that can be called and ten that cannot be called, the linker may include only the first five.

Comment: No, if a single object file in a library contains fifteen functions, and one of them is called, all fifteen functions will be included in the final binary, unless the compiler provided extra information in the object file (or split it up into one section per function), and the linker was told to use that extra information.

Comment: Technically the compiler and linker are separate operations.  But practically they're always used together, and might even be the same program.  So it's a semantic quibble to argue whether it's the compiler or linker that's responsible.